# different n (offset) for shift within each group

Tags: r, data.table

Would like compute the elapsed time between action A and action X. There is different logic for other actions (B,C etc.) but they involve doing similar time differences.

Is there a way to use computed value for offset in shift? I have used shift in the past for fixed offset e.g. using lag to go back 12 rows within a group but can't figure how to incorporate conditional offset in shift

Here's a made up example:

```
x <- data.table(Case = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3), Action = c("A","B","C","X","A","X","X","A","C","X","A","X"), ActionTime = parse_date_time(c("1/23/2020 12:55","1/26/20 3:23","1/28/2020 4:23","4/16/2020 17:50","1/25/2020 23:04","2/12/2020 17:50","2/13/2020 17:50","1/26/2020 3:23","2/18/2020 21:23","2/18/2020 21:27","3/15/2020 3:23","3/18/2020 21:27"), orders=c('mdy HM')))
setkeyv(x, c("Case", "ActionTime"))

    > x
    Case Action          ActionTime
 1:    1      A 2020-01-23 12:55:00
 2:    1      B 2020-01-26 03:23:00
 3:    1      C 2020-01-28 04:23:00
 4:    1      X 2020-04-16 17:50:00
 5:    2      A 2020-01-25 23:04:00
 6:    2      X 2020-02-12 17:50:00
 7:    2      X 2020-02-13 17:50:00
 8:    3      A 2020-01-26 03:23:00
 9:    3      C 2020-02-18 21:23:00
10:    3      X 2020-02-18 21:27:00
11:    3      A 2020-03-15 03:23:00
12:    3      X 2020-03-18 21:27:00
```

Case 1 is the simple case, Case 2 when Action X shows multiple times but I need the min value of time and Group 3 where A and X show multiple times within the same case.

I am looking to get XTime = the timestmp of the closest X after the occurrence of A within the case:

```
    Case Action          ActionTime          XTime
 1:    1      A 2020-01-23 12:55:00          2020-04-16 17:50:00
 2:    1      B 2020-01-26 03:23:00
 3:    1      C 2020-01-28 04:23:00
 4:    1      X 2020-04-16 17:50:00
 5:    2      A 2020-01-25 23:04:00          2020-02-12 17:50:00
 6:    2      X 2020-02-12 17:50:00
 7:    2      X 2020-02-13 17:50:00
 8:    3      A 2020-01-26 03:23:00          2020-02-18 21:27:00
 9:    3      C 2020-02-18 21:23:00
10:    3      X 2020-02-18 21:27:00
11:    3      A 2020-03-15 03:23:00          2020-03-18 21:27:00
12:    3      X 2020-03-18 21:27:00
```

Appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your chances of getting an answer will greatly increase if you provide a simple, self-contained example of your problem. This would include toy input data, your code, any error messages, and expected output. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) may be helpful.

Comment: Hi Murali, welcome to Stack Overflow. I agree with Limey that it's not clear what your expected output is. I edited your question to provide the data with better formatting. I would recommend to copy that table and [edit] your question with a second copy that provides your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with a rolling join.

First, we subset the data on `Action == "A"` and `Action == "X"` and join the two subsets onto each other. We use `on = c("Case","Time")` to join on cases that are the same and then time. In `data.table`, you can only roll on the last join condition. We then use `roll = Inf` to roll forward. For some reason, the column you roll on is combined during the join, so we create and extra copy called `InitialTime`.

The rolling join rolls forward to all possible value in the positive direction, so then we subset by `Case` to the minimum `Time` for all combinations of `Case` and `InitialTime`.

```
library(data.table)
data[Action == "A",.(Case,Action,Time,InitialTime=Time)][
  data[Action == "X",], on = c("Case","Time"), roll = Inf][
    ,.SD[which.min(Time),.(XTime=Time)],by = .(Case,InitialTime)]
   Case         InitialTime               XTime
1:    1 2020-01-23 12:55:00 2020-04-16 17:50:00
2:    2 2020-01-25 23:04:00 2020-02-12 17:50:00
3:    3 2020-01-26 03:23:00 2020-02-18 21:27:00
4:    3 2020-03-15 03:23:00 2020-03-18 21:27:00
```

**Sample Data**

```
data <- structure(list(Case = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), Action = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "X"), class = "factor"), 
    Time = structure(c(1579802100, 1580026980, 1580203380, 1587073800, 
    1580011440, 1581547800, 1581634200, 1580026980, 1582078980, 
    1582079220, 1584256980, 1584581220), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Another possibility may be `data[Action == "A", XTime := data[Action == "X"][.SD, on = c("Case","ActionTime"), x.ActionTime, roll = -Inf]]`

Comment: Thank you. Found this very helpful. Introduced me to rolling joins, which is incredibly  powerful

Comment: @MuraliNarayanaswamy Glad it helped you. Also note that there is `roll = "nearest"`, which comes in handy quite frequently.